# For loop question-Simulating a robot' s movement on a 2d array

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

i' m trying to simulate a robot' s movement on a 2d array. In my case, robot goes forward firstly, if it sees a engel, it turns left and continues its movement. The problem is that, i could not present turning left and moving on left-direction on the initial matrix.

Here' s my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define x 7                                         //Matrix dimensions
#define y 7

const int trigPin = 12;
const int echoPin = 11;

Servo myServo;                                     //variable definations
Servo myServo2;

int pos = 0;

int counter;
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2;
int counter3;

int integer;
int integer2;
int integer4;

long duration;
long distance;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    myServo.attach(9);
    myServo2.attach(10);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
}

void loop() {
    int my2dArray[x][y] = {                          // initial matrix
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    };
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    int robot = my2dArray[3][3];                   // first place of robot

    if (counter1 > 0) {
        for (integer = 0;  integer < counter1; integer += 1) {
            if (distance < 10) {                                  //seeing     the object
                for (pos = 0; pos <= 180 ; pos += 1) {              //turning left
                    myServo.write(pos);
                }

                for (pos = 0; pos <= 180  ; pos += 1) {            //moving on after turning
                    myServo.write(pos);
                    myServo2.write(pos);

                    if (pos == 180) {
                        counter3 +=  1;
                    }
                }

                Serial.println(integer);

                for (integer4 = 0;  integer4 < counter3; integer4 += 1) {     //modifying matrix if there is an object
                    my2dArray[3 + integer][3 + integer4] = robot * my2dArray[3 + integer][3 + integer4];
                }

                Serial.println("Break condition.");
                break;
            } else {
                my2dArray[3 + integer][3] = robot * my2dArray[3 + integer][3];    //modifying matrix in case of there is no object
            }
        }
    }

    for (integer2 = 0; integer2 < 7; integer2++) {                          //displaying matrix
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][0]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][1]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][2]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][3]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][4]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.print(my2dArray[integer2][5]);
        Serial.print("|");
        Serial.println(my2dArray[integer2][6]);
    }

    Serial.println();

    for (pos = 0; pos <= 180  ; pos += 1) {                               // moving forward as first movement
        myServo.write(pos);
        myServo2.write(pos);

        if (pos == 180) {
            counter1 +=  1;
        }
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

The problem part is:

```
for (integer4 = 0;  integer4 < counter3; integer4 += 1){      //modifying matrix if there is an object

    my2dArray[3 + integer][3+integer4] = robot * my2dArray[3 + integer][3+integer4];

     }
```

"integer" value does not change in the problem part, it' s always 0 in despite of the first for loop. How can i pass the "integer" to the problem part properly?

Comment: Those variable names are really confusing. You really should name them after what they represent, not the data type that is in them.

Comment: Also you really should learn to format your code properly. It makes it so much easier to follow. I have done it for you this time, but you really do need to learn about proper indenting.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is hard to follow with all those meaningless "integer" and "counter" variables, and the logic seems a little odd in places, but I believe the cause of your problems is the `break` statement:

```
for (integer = 0; integer < counter1; integer += 1) {
    if (distance < 10) {
        // ...
        for (integer4 = 0;  integer4 < counter3; integer4 += 1) {     //modifying matrix if there is an object
            my2dArray[3 + integer][3 + integer4] = robot * my2dArray[3 + integer][3 + integer4];
        }
        break; // << HERE
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of that `break`? I think you are using it to jump out of the `if` so that it doesn't run the `else`, which it *won't run anyway since it's an else condition*. Instead, what the `break` is actually doing is terminating the `for` loop after the first iteration that hits that inner `if` condition. That is, as long as the distance is less than 10 it will only ever run the `for` once, and so `integer` will only ever be 0.